# What is the purpose of exclamation marks in field definitions for GraphQL types in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm following [this guide](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/2-queries/) to learn GraphQL with a Ruby backend, and in the section "Query for Returning Links", there is the following code:

```
# defines a new GraphQL type
Types::LinkType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  # this type is named `Link`
  name 'Link'

  # it has the following fields
  field :id, !types.ID
  field :url, !types.String
  field :description, !types.String
end
```

I know that the exclamation mark is simply a 'not' operator, but can anybody explain its purpose here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mandatory (non-nullable) field. Implementation of:

> String! means that the field is non-nullable, meaning that the GraphQL service promises to always give you a value when you query this field. In the type language, we'll represent those with an exclamation mark.

https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields

It seems it was replaced by keyword syntax:

```
field :handle, String, null: false
```

http://graphql-ruby.org/type_definitions/objects.html

Comment: Does it not matter if the exclamation mark comes before or after the type then? Reading this document, all non-nullables are **followed** by it, not preceeded by it: [GraphQL Ruby - Non-Null Types](http://graphql-ruby.org/type_definitions/non_nulls.html) - whereas in [this documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/GraphQL/Field), it is used to preceed the type, but without explanation...?

Comment: In Ruby graphql DSL it goes before the type because it's used a an overloaded operator then - `!(types.String)`. It's mapped to `types.String!` in graphql schema definition.

It `types.String!` were uses, it'd be treated as a part of the type name: `String!`

Comment: Great, thanks! With your help, I found [this documentation](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/guides/schema/class_based_api.md) which states that it has now been removed to avoid ambiguity with the built-in logical operator.

Comment: Sure you can! :)

Answer (score 2):

"!" mark in GraphQL specifies that field is not nullable. In your example none of the fields id, url, description can be NULL.

```
field :id, !types.ID
field :url, !types.String
field :description, !types.String
```

It has slightly different meaning if used in lists.

[Int]! : List can not be NULL. If you pass "null" that would be an error while "[1, 2, null]" is acceptable. 
[Int!] : Content of list can not be NULL. It will accept "null" list but "[1, 2, null]" would result in error.